# How to `geth init` and start geth mining with Docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ethereum, geth

I want to create private ethereum network with Docker. I've prepared genesis file so i need to `geth init genesis.json` and then start mining like `geth --mine ...`. I can do it with scripts (like here: https://github.com/vertigobr/ethereum/blob/master/runminer.sh#L5 and https://github.com/vertigobr/ethereum/blob/master/runnode.sh#L23):

```
if [ ! -d $DATA_ROOT/keystore ]; then
    echo "$DATA_ROOT/keystore not found, running 'geth init'..."
    docker run --rm \
        -v $DATA_ROOT:/root/.ethereum \
        -v $(pwd)/genesis.json:/opt/genesis.json \
        $IMGNAME init /opt/genesis.json
    echo "...done!"
fi
echo "Running new container $CONTAINER_NAME..."
docker run $DETACH_FLAG --name $CONTAINER_NAME \
    --network ethereum \
    -v $DATA_ROOT:/root/.ethereum \
    -v $DATA_HASH:/root/.ethash \
    -v $(pwd)/genesis.json:/opt/genesis.json \
    $RPC_PORTMAP \
    $IMGNAME --bootnodes=$BOOTNODE_URL $RPC_ARG --cache=512 --verbosity=4 --maxpeers=3 ${@:2}
```

Since it seems to be 2-step process how can i do it with Docker-compose?

If i override `command:` for mining service, what should i write? If i write just `geth init`, then it will not start mining. If i try to join and write `command: init genesis.json --mine ...` it hurts:

```
version: "3"

services:
  eth_miner:
    image: ethereum/client-go:v1.7.3
    ports:
      - "8545:8545"
    volumes:
      - ${DATA_ROOT}:/root/.ethereum
      - ${GENESIS_FILE}:/opt/genesis.json
    command: init /opt/genesis.json --rpc --rpcaddr=0.0.0.0 --rpcapi=db,eth,net,web3,personal --rpccorsdomain "*" --nodiscover --cache=512 --verbosity=4 --mine --minerthreads=3 --networkid 15 --etherbase="${ETHERBASE}" --gasprice=${GASPRICE}
```

log:

```
Attaching to 7adbb760_eth_miner_1
eth_miner_1  | Incorrect Usage: flag provided but not defined: -rpc
eth_miner_1  | 
eth_miner_1  | init [command options] [arguments...]
eth_miner_1  | 
eth_miner_1  | The init command initializes a new genesis block and definition for the network.
eth_miner_1  | This is a destructive action and changes the network in which you will be
eth_miner_1  | participating.
eth_miner_1  | 
eth_miner_1  | It expects the genesis file as argument.
eth_miner_1  | 
eth_miner_1  | ETHEREUM OPTIONS:
eth_miner_1  |   --datadir "/root/.ethereum"  Data directory for the databases and keystore
eth_miner_1  | 
eth_miner_1  | DEPRECATED OPTIONS:
eth_miner_1  |   --light  Enable light client mode
eth_miner_1  | 
eth_miner_1  | flag provided but not defined: -rpc
7adbb760_eth_miner_1 exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best option is creating a shell script which do the initialization and then run geth, should be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -d /root/.ethereum/keystore ]; then
    echo "/root/.ethereum/keystore not found, running 'geth init'..."
    geth init /opt/genesis.json
    echo "...done!"
fi

geth "$@"
```

And docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  eth_miner:
    image: ethereum/client-go:v1.7.3
    ports:
      - "8545:8545"
    volumes:
      - ${DATA_ROOT}:/root/.ethereum
      - ${GENESIS_FILE}:/opt/genesis.json
      - ./init-script.sh:/root/init-script.sh
    entrypoint: /root/init-script.sh
    command: --bootnodes=$BOOTNODE_URL $RPC_ARG --cache=512 --verbosity=4 --maxpeers=3 ${@:2}
```

Comment: The option "command" in docker-compose.yml just pass "/root/init-script.sh --bootnodes= ..." to docker-entrypoint.sh as an argument. I'm afraid entry point can be `geth`. If it is then it will not work (unless we can override entry point cmd too).

Comment: My mistake, just edited the answer. I forgot to modify the entrypoint.

Comment: thanks for editing, i've checked entry point is really `geth`, so we need to override it too.

Comment: i believe in general case running script like this can solve the problem. in this particular case i'm getting "permission denied" for both `/root/init-script.sh` and `/opt/init-script.sh`

Comment: Run chmod +x init-script.sh

Comment: some required changes: `entrypoint: sh /root/init-script.sh` and/or `#!/bin/sh` in script